# Make height proportional to width of an image CSS

Tags: css

I want to make height proportional to width of an image where width is 20%. Please Help me using CSS

Comment: Do not specify any `height`, it should be automatically proportional.

Comment: Just specify the width. The browser should maintain the aspect ratio for you.

Comment: Current Code? Browser? Anything?

Comment: There are 2 ways you can do it
1) Leave height as blank
2) Set height as Auto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can use this way:

```
width: 20%;
height: auto;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
```

For **Internet Explorer 7**, you need to use `-ms-interpolation-mode` to make it look proportional.

**Note:**

> The `-ms-interpolation-mode` property applies to stretched images only. For example, if the natural width of the image is `200x200` but the page designer specifies that the height and width should be `400x400`, then the image will be stretched to the new dimensions using the nearest-neighbor algorithm, unless otherwise specified.
>
> Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530822(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just set `width: 20%;` and leave height to its default value, that is `auto`.